# Field goes null when button press oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am creating form for search data in oracle forms 10g

when user select LOV from non-database field and press search button then non-database field goes null. I want field not null when button press

Answer (score 0):

A screenshot would help; it is unclear where's that non-database field placed. If it is a tabular layout forum, is it placed within all the other fields? Or is it somewhere in a control, non-database block?

Anyway: here's how I'd do that.

First of all, if possible, avoid *inventing* your own searching algorithm. Forms is *very good* at doing such things by itself. Shortly:

- enter query mode
- enter search criteria (select it from a list of values; why not?)
- execute query
- absolutely no additional programming is necessary (apart from the LoV)

If, for some reason, you have to do it "your way":

- put the non-database LoV field into a separate control block
- `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` should

  - use `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY` and set database block's `DEFAULT_WHERE` (or, maybe even better, `ONETIME_WHERE`) to a selected LoV value
  - navigate to a database block (`GO_BLOCK`)
  - `EXECUTE_QUERY`
- alternatively, `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` would only `EXECUTE_QUERY`, but you'd use `PRE-QUERY` trigger on the database block that sets the searching criteria, for example `:database_block.name := :control_block.lov_field;`

As of your question:

- it seems that the LoV field is part of the database block, and it gets cleared once you execute query. See if you can re-fill it using `POST-QUERY` trigger
- Or, if it is not, check what the `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger is doing - maybe it clears it

See of what I wrote helps. If not, please, edit the question (your initial message) and provide additional information which would help us help you.